# $L_p$ norm of linear function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there a nice formula for the $L_p$ norm of $f(\vec{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ on the domain $[-1,1]^n$, where $\vec{x} = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$?

i.e. a nice expression for $\left(\int_{\vec{x} \in [-1,1]^n}  \left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right|^p dx_1 \dots dx_n\right)^\frac{1}{p}$

Comment: You forgot absolute values around the sum. Also, it might be useful (for $p=2$ it surely is) to note that this is the same as the $L^p $ Norm of $\sum_i X^i $, where $X_1,\dots,X_n $ are independent and uniformly distributed in $[-1,1] $.